# swift comparing NSDates

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

i have two `NSDate` object that i want to compare with the following code :

```
    var endDate = self.object.endDate
    var thisDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateFromComponents(currentComponents)

    let test = thisDate?.compare(endDate) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending

    do {
        timeRangeArray.addObject(thisDate!)
        currentComponents.minute += 15
        thisDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateFromComponents(currentComponents)
    } while thisDate?.compare(endDate) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending  {
        return timeRangeArray
    }
```

and always getting - `(() -> () -> $T8) -> $T9 is not identical to NSComparsionResult`

i don't want to create another value for while statement, is there any other way to make this work ?

Comment: Why do you have braces (`{` `}`) around your `return` statement? That converts it into a block as part of your expression.

Comment: thank you, i missed that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [do-while statement](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/while-statement) looks like this:

```
do {
    statements
} while condition
```

Yours looks like this:

```
do {
    statements
} while condition {
    // what is this???
}
```

I think you meant:

```
do {
    timeRangeArray.addObject(thisDate!)
    currentComponents.minute += 15
    thisDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateFromComponents(currentComponents)
} while thisDate?.compare(endDate) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending  

return timeRangeArray
```